# html2jade : converting html 2 jade with tabs as indentation

Tags: html, node.js, pug

Using html2jade to convert html files to jade.

1. But, it's using 2 white spaces as indentation and couldn't see a way to configure tab character as indentation. Is there any config option to specify the indentation character as tab?

Also, facing issue in converting html to jade if html has commented blocks like:

```
<div id='view-templates'>
    <!--<div id='project-view'>
        <div id='toolbar'>
            <div id='top-list'></div>
            <div id='intvl-options'></div>
            <div id='display-options'></div>
        </div>
        <div id='top-chart'>
        </div>
        <div id='bw-chart'>
        </div>
    </div>-->
</div>
```

The above code snippet is translated as:

```
#view-templates
  //
    <div id='project-view'>
            <div id='toolbar'>
                <div id='top-list'></div>
                <div id='intvl-options'></div>
                <div id='display-options'></div>
            </div>
            <div id='top-chart'>
            </div>
            <div id='bw-chart'>
            </div>
        </div>
```

1. Looks it's not converting the commented HTML to jade resulting in invalid indentation. Is there any config option to exclude comments while converting to jade?

Comment: were you able to solve this problem? I'm curious too

Comment: Using scalate to convert html to jade ignores the commented HTML content: http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/htmlConvert.html

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no set way to use tabs or spaces. But you can go from one to the other without any problem. That is if you change all tabs to spaces or vice versa, Jade will understand what is being written so, but must be the entire document or file must be changed.

Recommendation, be very careful with whitespace and comments here.

Comment: Please stop vandalizing your posts. Kindly let the mods know if you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can switch from spaces to tabs in your text editor. For instance with Sublime :

1. Paste the result of html2jade in Sublime
2. in View menu -> Indentation, choose Tab Width : 2.
3. Again in the View menu -> Indentation click Convert Indentations to tabs.

The job is done.

As regards your first question : it indeed looks like the jade convertor is taking html comments as *not to be translated*, which is logical in a point of view. You can easily set back block comments in jade after with :

```
//
  this is a
  block comment
```

Comment: This is really more of a workaround and not a direct solution. Jade uses tabs or spaces, but not both. It would be more accurate to suggest that a preprocessor to be used to convert the indent spaces to tabs before sending it to Jade.